# A property of an open convex set in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and convex, so that $s x + (1-s)y \in A$ for all $x,y \in A$ and $s \in [0,1]$. It it true that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that we also have
$$
t x + (1-t)y \in A \quad \forall t \in(-\delta, 1+\delta). \tag{1}
$$
For example, consider $t \in (1, 1+\delta)$, where $\delta>0$ is still to be determined. Since $A$ is open, for any $z(s):=sx+(1-s)y$, $s \in [0, 1]$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(z(s)) \subset S$. Can this be used to show $(1)$?

Comment: You do not need to construct balls for every point on $z(s)$ just its endpoints $x,y$.  From there, you use those balls (in particular, their radii) in order to prove (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1 < t < 1+\delta$ and $x,y \in A$ is
$$
 \Vert \bigl(tx + (1-t)y \bigr) - x\Vert = |1-t| \cdot \Vert x-y \Vert < \delta \cdot \Vert x-y \Vert
$$
so that
$$
 tx + (1-t)y \in B_{\delta \cdot \Vert x-y \Vert}(x)
$$
and that ball is a subset of $A$ for sufficiently small $\delta$ because $x$ is an interior point of $A$.

A similar calculation works for $-\delta < t < 0$. The convexity of $A$ is not needed for this argument.

Comment: I have silently assumed that $x \ne y$ since the statement is trivially true if $x=y$.